# SimplePolygon.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class SimplePolygon
{
    Point[] pointCollection;

    public SimplePolygon(Point[] pointCollection)
    {
        this.pointCollection = pointCollection;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(pointCollection, null) || (pointCollection.Count() == 0))
            return pointCollection.GetHashCode();
        int hash = 17;
        for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.Count(); i++)
            hash = hash * 23 + pointCollection[i].GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return false;

        if (!(obj is SimplePolygon))
            return false;

        if (this.pointCollection.Count() != (obj as SimplePolygon).pointCollection.Count())
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.pointCollection.Count(); i++)
            if (!(obj as SimplePolygon).pointCollection.Contains(this.pointCollection[i]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

My problem is that Equals method and GetHashCode method are not consistent:

```
Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
//...create and initialize p1, p2, p3, p4.

SimplePolygon polygon1 = new SimplePolygon(p1, p2, p3, p4);
SimplePolygon polygon2 = new SimplePolygon(p4, p3, p2, p1);

polygon1 == polygon2; //this is true
polygon1.GetHashCode() == polygon2.GetHashCode(); //this is false
```

And this violates the rule that says that two objects that are equal should have the same hash code.

My problem is that the hash code is generated going from the first element of the array to the last, while the Equals method does not care about the order of Points in the array(for simple polygons or non intersecting polygons, the order of points is irelevant - (p1, p2, p3, p4) is the same as (p2, p3, p4, p1) or (p3, p4, p1, p2) or (p4, p3, p2, p1))

Does anyone know a good method for generating hash codes for such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.Count(); i++)
    hash = hash * 23 + pointCollection[i].GetHashCode();
```

e.g. to

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.Count(); i++)
    hash += pointCollection[i].GetHashCode();
```

so it doesn't depend on the order of the points.

Comment: it doesn't depend on the order..but the resulting hash will be wrong

Comment: ah, I just realized: if the hashes are the same, that doesn't mean the polygon has to be equal, right? if that's the case, your solution is correct!

Comment: @duedl0r: Different polygons may have the same hash. This is called hash collision. Hash collision may have a performance impact, but the hash is certainly not wrong. As leppie notes, even the length of the collection is a valid hash.

Comment: but, you're right: "wrong" is the wrong word :) maybe "not optimal" is better.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be, that you find out a good starting point. E.g. you find the the left most point and start calculation your hash from there..

Comment: I think the best solution is to store the polygon's points in a separate list, ordered by X and Y, and to construct the hash from this list. This way, the order of points is not important and also hash collisions are avoided.

Comment: Hmm..Your this solution only works if the polygon is convex. If the polygon can be concave it is important to have the correct ordering of the points.

Comment: Yes ... you are right. The problem with taking the left most point, is that starting calculation to the left or to the right, should generate the same hash. That is if p2 is the left most point then p2->p3->p4->p1 and p2->p1->p4->p3 is the same. I guess this aproach is not good :((

Comment: Fair enough, but if you need this, you also have a problem in your `Equals` function. As for the hash, you could calculate your hash two times (one clockwise and one counter-clockwise) then add them and use that as hash. But I'm not sure whether this is a good hash.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your hashing algorithm. Eg: Just return say the length of `pointCollection`. You can probably fine tune it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are using your SimplePolygon class, but from the class name I would expect it to define a single connected region.

As such the order of the points may be relevant to equality. For an example, take the Nepalese (5 sided) flag. If we number the vertexes clockwise from the top as p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 then the polygon obtained by drawing edges in the ordering p1, p3, p2, p4, p5 is different from the flag as normally seen.

If these two shapes should not be considered equal, then equality reduces to down to whether the 2 objects have point collections which are a cyclic permutation of each other. This would still work within duedl0r or Henrik's hash method - I would use one of them (Henrik's seems likely to cause fewer hash collisions) and then profile to see if hash collisions are causing problems.

Comment: Yes you are right ... i did not explain very well ... the polygons whos collections are a cyclic permutation of each other, are equal.